# How to use VBA inlineshape to disable overlay of pictures

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2016

The word document have many pictures. The pictures should show one pre page. Normally I just need to select them all to insert. All of them will occupy in good order one picture per page.

However, sometimes, word overlay them together. Resulting only one page with many pictures stacking up each other.

I find some VBA script that change the scale of pictures. I want to change that to disable overlap of pictures or change the wrap settings of them.

```
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument
    For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
        With .InlineShapes(i)
            .ScaleHeight = 50
            .ScaleWidth = 50
        End With
    Next i
End With
```

How to change the above script to disable them overlay each other ?

Comment: If pictures are stacked or overlapping, they are _not_ inline with text. What happens if you open _File>Options>Advanced_, scroll to the _Cut, copy and paste_ section and change the _Insert/paste picture as_ dropdown to _In line with text_? Does the problem go away?

Comment: No

Already try that. Does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As John says:

> If pictures are stacked or overlapping, they are *not* inline with
> text.

You can correct that with code like:

```
With ActiveDocument
    Do While .Shapes.Count > 0
        .Shapes(1).ConvertToInlineShape
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: The pictures were inline. I find out that I have set the paragraph height to fixed 12pt. 

If reset the paragraph height to normal single line height then the pictures were ok